# Calling a asynchronous function within a utils.js file (React-Native)?

Tags: react-native, async-await, geolocation

I am building a weather app in react-native for my portfolio.

I would like to be able to call a helper function within my utils.js file. The function is a asynchronous arrow function and is responsible for retrieving latitude and longitude coordinates.

The function returns the coordinates in an array and I use destructing in order to set state in the component.

However, I am getting a warning in my console stating the following:

> WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection  (id: 1): TypeError:
> undefined is not an object (evaluating
> '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[11],
> "../Utils/utils").globalFunctions.getLocation')

What could I possibly be doing wrong? Any help would be appericated.

Utils.js

```
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';

const globalFunctions = {
  getLocation: async () => {
const coordinates = [];
const hasLocationPermission = await 
PermissionsAndroid.request(
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
);

if (hasLocationPermission == PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    position => {
      console.log('Geolocation Granted');
      console.log(position);
      const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      const longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      coordinates.push(latitude);
      coordinates.push(longitude);
      return coordinates;
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error.code, error.message);
    },
    {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000},
  );
} else {
  console.log('User denied Geolocation');
}
```

},
};

WeatherContainer.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, Image, StyleSheet, View, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import {globalFunctions} from '../Utils/utils';

class WeatherContainer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      lat: null,
      lon: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getLocationData();
  };

  getLocationData = async () => {
    const [latitude, longitude] = await globalFunctions.getLocation();
    this.setState({
      lat: latitude,
      lon: longitude,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.location}>{this.state.lat}</Text>
          <Text>{this.state.lon}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're not exporting anything from `Utils.js`

Answer (score 0):

You need to export globalFunctions function from Utils.js

```
const export globalFunctions
```